# Создание коллажа с помощью Python

Tags: python

я понимаю, что никто за меня код писать не будет, но надеюсь меня натолкнут на ход или библиотеку)
У меня есть список ссылок или уже скачанные изображения (без разницы), и мне нужно с помощью кода Python создать коллаж (изображений ≈ 100). Предложите пожалуйста библиотеку или код)

Comment: Вот библиотека и примеры. Режете, крутите и склеиваете https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-images-python/amp/

Comment: На `kivy` это можно сделать не сложно с помощью `Scatter`